# imprimir os resultados do Objeto Map com JSTL/JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, foreach-jstl

Boa noite pessoal, gostaria de saber como faço para imprimir os valores do Objeto de retorno do Map com jstl?
Eu tentei fazer com forEach, porém os valores não retorna nada.
Segue a minha implementação:

index.jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${sedes}" var="sedesMap">
    <p>${sedesMap.value.sedeId}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

Valores retornado do Map:

```
[
    {
        23=Sede [
            sedeId=9, 
            sedeBairro=Tupuiu,
            ...
        ]
    }, 
    {
        53=Sede [
           sedeId=26,
           sedeBairro=São Bernardo do Campos,
           ...
       ]
    },
    {
       53=Sede [
           sedeId=30,
           sedeBairro=São José do Campos,
           ...
       ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem certeza que a sua map tem os valores sendo passados para o jsp? Sem ver o código do seu servlet fica mais difícil.

Teoricamente seria assim no servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HashMap<String, String> myHash = new HashMap<>();
    myHash.put("a","b");
    myHash.put("c","d");

    request.setAttribute("themap", myHash);

    request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

e com o jstl no jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>THE MAP</h1>
<c:forEach var="type" items="${themap}">
   K = ${type.key}
   V = ${type.value}
   <br />
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```